# How can I tell if a CSS file has loaded that I've included via JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some jQuery that loads a new stylesheet like so...

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + config.basePath + config.stylesheetsPath + 'sections/' + name + '.css" media="screen" class="new site-specific" />');
```

I am then attempting to get some info from that CSS file immediately after. It generally will not display the correct information until the second trigger of the event (after I imagine the stylesheet has loaded).

Is there any event I can attach to trigger when the CSS is loaded?

Comment: What info do you need from the stylesheet? Once the stylesheet is loaded, it will appropriately change the look of the site.

Comment: I need to get a colour from it - and then fade the current background to the new one.

Comment: I suggest storing that colour in a more productive way.

Comment: I thought about that, but I've segmented the colours into their own CSS files - it makes the CSS more modular and specific to their content. However, I may need to store them in the common.css file if I can't get this to work.

Comment: Can't you just make an ajax call to the css file? This way you have an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about triggering an event, but can you make an get request for the CSS file and then just update the `<head>` with a new `<style>` tag, placing the content of the file inside the `<style>` tag?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $.get("http://example.com/style.css", function(data) {
      $('head').append("<style>" + data + "</style>");
   });
   ... /* your code */ ...
});
```

Comment: This works, except the image paths are pointing to different areas once they are included like this.

Comment: That may be because the relative paths used in the CSS file are not valid from the HTML file.  You can use absolute paths or update the relative paths as though the css file was in the same directory as the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is some kind of "onload" event for the CSS (and there should be, as firebug will show such a thing), I would use the following procedure:
1. Put a hidden DOM element with color X.
2. in the uploaded CSS this color will be changed to y
3. Once you initiate the upload (in your JS) you create a listner that will rise what ever function you want when the color changes to y.

By listner I mean use setInterval.