# jQuery: loading css on demand + callback if done

Tags: jquery, css, load

I want to load CSS files on demand (by eg. running an XML HTTP request which returns the CSS files to be loaded) for example **style1.css**, **style2.css** ..

So is there a way in jQuery (or a plugin) to this?

- bulk-loading several files + adding all those CSS-files into the dom
- when finished loading: firing a callback (like alerting "all stylesheets are finished loaded!");

the idea is: loading `html` via `xmlhttp`, loading +adding **required** css-files,
then - after anything is finished, display that `html`.

any idea?

Thanx!

Answer (score 24):

How to load **multiple** CSS files **with callback** as requested 
*Note: ithout xdomain permissions, $.get will only load local files*

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gb6umvq0/1/) 
*Note that the text "all css loaded" appears after loading but before the CSS is applied. Perhaps another workaround is required to overcome that.*

```
$.extend({
    getManyCss: function(urls, callback, nocache){
        if (typeof nocache=='undefined') nocache=false; // default don't refresh
        $.when.apply($,
            $.map(urls, function(url){
                if (nocache) url += '?_ts=' + new Date().getTime(); // refresh? 
                return $.get(url, function(){                    
                    $('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':url}).appendTo('head');                    
                });
            })
        ).then(function(){
            if (typeof callback=='function') callback();
        });
    },
});
```

Usage

```
var cssfiles=['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css'];

$.getManyCss(cssfiles, function(){
    // do something, e.g.
    console.log('all css loaded');
});
```

to force refresh the css files add true

```
$.getManyCss(cssfiles, function(){
    // do something, e.g.
    console.log('all css loaded');
}, true);
```

Comment: +1. For everybody else that wonders: The solution does not fire a callback when the css is loaded (as demanded in the question). But since the resource is fetched beforehand, the callback that fires after $.get() resolves will fire immediately, as the resource is in the browsers cache. Nice solution indeed, should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The resources load and as soon as they load they are appended to the page. When all are loaded the callback fires. I will test whether the callback executes before the link is added to head.

Comment: @Dyna You're right, it triggers after all $.get()s resolve but before it takes effect. I don't like the solution but I might be tempted to use setInterval to see when the last `<link>` is added. A simple fix would be `if (typeof callback=='function') setTimeout(callback, 500);` A delay of 0 which works for some problems wasn't adequate. There must be a cleaner way....

Comment: Please note that this does not ensure that the style-sheets will be appended in the given order. To perform that, you'll have to loop through the style-sheets and append them to the `head` as `<link>` inside the `then` part of the `when`.

Comment: @rolebi perhaps that would use a recursive function

Comment: @Popnoodles That was just an example, was waiting for an update of your answer actually :p

Comment: @Popnoodles   can you help me to find the solution for out this Q [Question  LINK___](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450997/jquery-load-function-not-work-proper-way-when-i-am-using-multi)

Comment: I expanded on this answer. The one I just provided doesn't call the resource twice.

Comment: @Popnoodles I edited your post as you had an incorrect function name in the "Usage" section, it said `getManyCss()` rather than `getCss()`. Hope that was OK?

Comment: @SaschaM78 No it was supposed to be getManyCss because that's what it does.

Comment: @Popnoodles then please update the fiddle as it still uses `getCss()` rather than `getManyCss()`.

Comment: Updated, and taking @Alberto's mods into account. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The answer given by **@Popnoodles** is not correct because the callback is not executed after all items have been loaded, but rather when the $.each loop is finished. The reason is, that `$.each` operation does not return a Deferred object (which is expected by `$.when`).

Here is a corrected example:

```
$.extend({
    getCss: function(urls, callback, nocache){
        if (typeof nocache=='undefined') nocache=false; // default don't refresh
        $.when.apply($,
            $.map(urls, function(url){
                if (nocache) url += '?_ts=' + new Date().getTime(); // refresh? 
                return $.get(url, function(){                    
                    $('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':url}).appendTo('head');                    
                });
            })
        ).then(function(){
            if (typeof callback=='function') callback();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, it works. Although you'll have to switch `i` and `url` around in `function(i, url)` for it to really work.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Like @Alberto said, $.each doesn't return a Deferred object which is required for $.when. So, when using $.map, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I would load it:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var css = jQuery("<link>");
    css.attr({
      rel:  "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: "path/to/file/style.css"
    });
    $("head").append(css);
});
```

Comment: thx looks great but i need to load those css-files on demand after jQuery has already been loaded .. :/

Comment: Right, the $(document).ready event will fire after jQuery has already been loaded.

Comment: He probably means a click or some other action, $(document).ready() isn't really **on-demand** :) He should've specified however.

Comment: @Fuxi - so then just change `$(document).ready(...)` to whatever event you want to trigger it, e.g.: `$('selector').click(...)`.

Comment: This only answers half of the OP's question: the other half is 'firing a callback when finished loading'. Unfortunately adding .load(function(){}) to the created link doesn't cut the mustard...

Comment: -1 to the answer as it only covers half of the problem, which is the easy one. The hard thing is the callback after the css resource has loaded

Comment: @Dyna it's not hard at all

Comment: @Popnoodles I am very interested in your solution to that problem, mind sharing it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be improved a bit I think... First of all, when you use this lines of code:

```
...
$.get(url, function(){                    
    $('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':url}).appendTo('head');
});
...
```

You're really making 2 calls to retrieve the css: first in the `$.get` itself and a second time when you append the `<link>` into the `head`. Removing the `$.get` will also retrieve the css, but just once:

```
...
$('<link>', {rel:'stylesheet', type:'text/css', 'href':url}).appendTo('head');
...
```

But if you need to do more things (eg. loading a script file) while retrieving these css' before calling the callback function I think a better approach for this would be using **promises** instead of the `when...then` solution. You could do something like this:

```
var requests = []; //array which will contain every request we want to do before calling the callback function

$.map(urls, function(url) { //urls is the array of css files we want to load
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    defer.promise();

    //we add the deferred object to the requests array
    requests.push(defer);

    var cssEl = $('<link>', { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', 'href': url });
    cssEl.appendTo('head').on("load", function() {
        defer.resolve();
    });
});

var anotherRequest = $.ajax({...}); //eg. a script file
requests.push(anotherRequest);

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    // callback when all requests are done
});
```

This way, if some of the css takes some time to load, the callback function won't be executed until all of them are retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve lazy loading of your resources.
There are different plug ins to handle this kind of behavior.

I've can name this two:

- [Jquery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-plugins)
- [Lazy](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazy)

Two snippets from the plugins page to  show it's use:

**Jquery Plugins**

```
$.plugins({ path: '/scripts/', plugins: [        
    { id:'box', js:'box.js', css:'box/styles.css', sel:'a[rel*=box]', ext:'box', fn:'box' },        
]});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a').box();
});
```

**Lazy with dependencies:**

```
$.lazy('ui.draggable.js','draggable',{
'css':['modal.css','drag.css'],
'js':['ui.core.js']
});

// And then you use you plugins as you always do
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIS DOES NOT REQUIRE THE CSS FILE(S) TO BE LOADED MORE THAN ONCE**

Working off from the other established answers, I managed to come up with this, which seems to work similar to `jQuery.getScript()`:

```
(function($){

    $.extend({
        getCss: function(url, success) {

            if ($("head").children("style[data-url='"+url+"']").length) {
                console.warn("CSS file already loaded: "+url);
            }

            var deferred = $.Deferred(function(defer){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url
                    ,context: {defer:defer,url:url}
                    ,dataType: 'text'
                    ,cache: (function(){
                        var cache = $.ajaxSetup().cache;
                        if (cache === undefined) {cache = false;}
                        return cache;
                    })()
                })
                .then(
                    function(css, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        css = "\n\n/* CSS dynamically loaded by jQuery */\n\n"+css;
                        $('<style type="text/css" data-url="'+this.url+'">'+css+'</style>').appendTo("head");
                        this.defer.resolve(css, textStatus, jqXHR);
                    }
                    ,function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        this.defer.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                );
            });
            if ($.isFunction(success)) {deferred.done(success);}
            return deferred;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

It doesn't load the requested file more than once, which *DOES* require that the CSS content is statically stored in the head.  But, it makes sense considering that loading/evaluating JavaScript is different than how styling is accessible to the browser for rendering.

```
$.getCss('path/to/css/file.css')
.done(function(){
    console.log("Worked");
 })
.fail(function(){
    console.log("Failed");
});
```

So far I've tested it with Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  All seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to by dynamic (read: on demand) you can modify Whit's response to `loadCssFile()` and call that with the file you want to load.

```
function loadCssFile(pathToFile) {
    var css = jQuery("<link>");
    css.attr({
      rel:  "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: pathToFile
    });
    $("head").append(css);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load multiple CSS files, but want them to be loaded one by one, you can use solution below:

```
var getCss = function (url, callback) {
        $.get(url, function () {
            $('<link>', {rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', 'href': url}).appendTo('head');
            if (typeof callback == 'function') callback();
        });
    };
```

Define function above, then define array containing you wanted css files

```
var cssfiles = ['css/pic1.css', 'css/pic2.css',
    'css/pic3.css', 'css/pic4.css', 'css/pic5.css',
    'css/pic6.css', 'css/pic7.css', 'css/pic8.css',
    'css/pic9.css'];
```

Then define callback function that will call each css files in the array

```
var callback = function (index) {
    getCss(cssfiles[index], function () {
        if (index + 1 < cssfiles.length) {
            callback(index + 1);
        }
    });
};
```

then start function with first css file by giving its index

```
callback(0);
```