# Event after applied CSS rules on elements in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, css, dom, load

Is there an event after CSS rules applied to all elements in the DOM ?
i know that the binding `$(window).load()`, from jQuery, is fired when all js and css files are loaded.

But not when they are applied (there is a small delay of some milliseconds between applying and inlcuding dynamically, such as: `$('#design').attr('href', 'style.css') // design is an <link href="otherstyles.css">`).

Answer (score 3):

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571164/jquery-event-that-triggers-after-css-is-loaded), you could grab the contents of the CSS file with AJAX and then use jQuery's built in complete call to tell when the CSS has loaded.

Comment: thanks, good approach, but no solution / workaround for the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Such an event does not exist.

- For all attribute changes, you can listen to the [`DOMAttrModifed` mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified).
- Another option is to monitor specific style properties in an periodic function (interval),
- Another method is to modify the `jQuery.fn.css` method, to intercept style changes via the jQuery API. This assumes that all relevant CSS property updates are done via jQuery.

  ```
  (function($){
      var $css = $.fn.css;
      $.fn.css = function(a,c) {
          if (c == null) return $css.call(this, a);

          return this.each(function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              // Your function logic...
              // ...
              // Call original method
              $css.call($this, a, c);
          });
      };
  })(jQuery);
  ```

Comment: but the `DOMAttrModifed` event is just fired when the DOM element is directly styled, such as `style="color:red"`?

Comment: Yes... It is fired only when the attribute is modified

Comment: @M.Myer Also when the style is changed via e.g. `document.body.style.color = 'red';` or `$('body').css('color','red').`.