# How to determine if CSS has been loaded?

Tags: css, watin

How can i Assert that the CSS for a page has successfully loaded and applied its styles in Watin 2.1?

Comment: Try so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571164/jquery-event-that-triggers-after-css-is-loaded

Comment: @yAnTar - i'm not sure how that helps.. I don't want a bunch of ajax code in my pages that is only used for testing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After doing some research and writing up my answer, I stumbled upon [this link](http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/) that explains everything you need to know about CSS, when it is loaded and how you can check for it.

The link provided explains it so well, in fact, that I'm adding some quotes from it for future reference.
<sub>If you're curious, my answer was going to be #2 and a variation of #4.</sub>

### [When is a stylesheet really loaded?](http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/)

**...**

With that out of the way, let's see what we have here.

```
// my callback function 
// which relies on CSS being loaded function
CSSDone() {
    alert('zOMG, CSS is done');
};

// load me some stylesheet 
var url = "http://tools.w3clubs.com/pagr/1.sleep-1.css",
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    link = document.createElement('link');

link.type = "text/css"; 
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = url;

// MAGIC 
// call CSSDone() when CSS arrives
head.appendChild(link);
```

Options for the magic part, sorted from nice-and-easy to ridiculous

1. listen to link.onload
2. listen to link.addEventListener('load')
3. listen to link.onreadystatechange
4. setTimeout and check for changes in document.styleSheets
5. setTimeout and check for changes in the styling of a specific element you create but style with the new CSS

5th option is too crazy and assumes you have control over the content of the CSS, so forget it. Plus it checks for current styles in a timeout meaning it will flush the reflow queue and can be potentially slow. The slower the CSS to arrive, the more reflows. So, really, forget it.

So how about implementing the magic?

```
// MAGIC 

// #1   
link.onload = function () {
    CSSDone('onload listener');
};   

// #2   
if (link.addEventListener) {
    link.addEventListener('load', function() {
        CSSDone("DOM's load event");
    }, false);   
};   

// #3   
link.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var state = link.readyState;
    if (state === 'loaded' || state === 'complete') {
        link.onreadystatechange = null;
        CSSDone("onreadystatechange");
    }   
};

// #4   
var cssnum = document.styleSheets.length;
var ti = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.styleSheets.length > cssnum) {
        // needs more work when you load a bunch of CSS files quickly
        // e.g. loop from cssnum to the new length, looking
        // for the document.styleSheets[n].href === url
        // ...

        // FF changes the length prematurely :(
        CSSDone('listening to styleSheets.length change');
        clearInterval(ti);
    }   
}, 10);

// MAGIC ends
```

Comment: Check my answer which refers to an important subsequent update to the article @ShowScripter links to.

Answer (score 13):

There has been an update to the article lined to by @ShadowScripter. The new method purportedly works in all browsers, ***including FF.***

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = '@import "' + url + '"';

var fi = setInterval(function() {
  try {
    style.sheet.cssRules; // <--- MAGIC: only populated when file is loaded
    CSSDone('listening to @import-ed cssRules');
    clearInterval(fi);
  } catch (e){}
}, 10);  

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 2):

After page load you can verify the style on some of your elements something like this:

```
var style = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("class")).Style;
Assert.That(Style.Display, Is.StringContaining("none"));
Assert.That(Style.FontSize, Is.EqualTo("10px"));
```

And etc...

Comment: Ok, but that's really just part of the problem.  This only verifies that the style is applied, not that all styles are validly loaded.  For example, how can I ensure that given background-image has loaded as part of the style?  Checking the style will say the style has a background image, but how can I verify that this image is loaded and being displayed?

Comment: You can verify the element properties and etc... the visibility test can be done only by eyes. if you have solution for this i'll be glad to know the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since browser compatibility can vary, and new future browser standards subject to change, I would recommend a combination of the onload listener and adding CSS to the style sheet so you can listen for when the HTML elements z-index changes if you are using a single style sheet. Otherwise, use the function below with a new meta tag for each style.

Add the following to the CSS file that you are loading:

```
#*(insert a unique id for he current link tag)* {
    z-index: 0
}
```

Add the following to your script:

```
function whencsslinkloads(csslink, whenload ){
    var intervalID = setInterval(
        function(){
            if (getComputedStyle(csslink).zIndex !== '0') return;
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            csslink.onload = null;
            whenload();
        },
        125 // check for if it has loaded 8 times a second
    );
    csslink.onload = function(){
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        csslink.onload = null;
        whenload();
    }
}
```

## Example

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel=stylesheet id="EpicStyleID" href="the_style.css" />
        <script async href="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        CSS Loaded: <span id=result>no</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

`script.js`:

```
function whencsslinkloads(csslink, whenload ){
    var intervalID = setInterval(
        function(){
            if (getComputedStyle(csslink).zIndex !== '0') return;
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            csslink.onload = null;
            whenload();
        },
        125 // check for if it has loaded 8 times a second
    );
    csslink.onload = function(){
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        csslink.onload = null;
        whenload();
    }
}
/*************************************/
whencsslinkloads(
    document.getElementById('EpicStyleID'),
    function(){
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<font color=green></font>'
    }
)
```

`the_style.css`

```
#EpicStyleID {
    z-index: 0
}
```

**PLEASE do not** make your script load synchronously (without the `async` attribute) just so you can capture the link's onload event. There are better ways, like the method above.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if CSS Variable exists

```
var blnCSSLoaded = false;
var iCSSLoad = setInterval(function() {
    var bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    var fooBar = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--blnMyCSSInit');
    if(fooBar) {
        clearInterval(iCSSLoad);
        blnCSSLoaded = true;
    }
}, 200);
```

You have to define the Variable in the CSS like this

```
:root {
  --blnMyCSSInit: #0077bf;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a css custom property.

If I'm not mistaken, the big advantage of this over @jack-G's answer is the custom property doesn't actually need to be used in any way to set styles on dom elements.