# How to check if a <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css"> succeeded

Tags: jquery

I'm adding theme setting to my js application. The application should work also off-line, so I have to check if the remote style file (like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/jquery/jquery-ui.css`) exists and is reachable, otherwise I set the `href` in `<link rel="stylesheet">` to point to a local file.

Till now I used the following code, but with jQuery 2.1.3 it output on console a warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

elicited at line `jquery-2.1.3.js:8556` Well, I could ignore the warning...

```
url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/jquery/jquery-ui.css";

$.ajax({url: url,
    type: "HEAD",
    timeout: 1000,
    async: false,
    error: function() {url = 'css/jquery-ui.css';}
});
/* modify link statement to use url for href */
```

Searching for an alternative method, I tried to check if the link statement has loaded the new css after changing its href, something like:

```
$('#id_of_the_link_stmt').error(function() {
  console.log("New url not loaded, reverting to local file")
}).attr('href', url);
```

but it does not works.

Thanks for suggesting!

Comment: And simply making the AJAX request be async is not an option?

Comment: Which browser you use, or do you have this problem with all browsers ?

Comment: Maybe you should check [How to determine if CSS has been loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537039/how-to-determine-if-css-has-been-loaded) or [How to use Javascript to check and load CSS if not loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724606/how-to-use-javascript-to-check-and-load-css-if-not-loaded)

Comment: Why dont you just check whether a local file exists, if it does not exists then load the file from server and if you are not able to get the file then it means neither local file exists nor the browser is connected to internet.

Comment: Or just check if the browser has internet access, if it has, then fetch the file from server else search local.

Comment: @void how do you check if local file exists in user cache using javascript?

Comment: I guess the later method is better, Because it is the browser's responsibility to do some task like this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using alternate style-sheets and groups?

You can always include the base stylesheet and custom one as an alternate one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" title="base" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" title="base" />
```

In this case the custom.css is available and the browser will load him (only him) - In case its not available the browser will move to the first one (without the alternate) and will load him- e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" title="base" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom11111.css" title="base" />
```

Now the base.css is loaded because custom1111.css is not available.

Note that the group is defined by the `title` attribute - you can set many groups too - e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" title="base" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_custom.css" title="base" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css" title="nav" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav_custom.css" title="nav" />
```

Using JavaScript to switch style sheets:

You can disable a style-sheet by setting it to `disabled = true` use the title attribute to identify the proper style-sheet to disable or enable.

More reading and examples:

- [Alternate CSS Styles / Themes](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/switch-alternate-css-styles.shtml)
- [How to Use JavaScript to Change a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) Dynamically](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml)

Comment: Fantastic idea! Never though about alternate sheets. This solves the problem at the root. Now I'll test it.

Comment: Good luck and don't forget to read more in the links i provided there are more you can do with this concept.

Comment: "alternate" is so helpful. I'm using one default and one alternate (in case it exists) now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that works is to put in `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" title="theme"/>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" id="ui-theme" title="theme"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

And in the theme changing code:

```
url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/"+theme_name+"/jquery-ui.css";
$('#ui-theme').attr('href', url);
```

So if the user is offline, the local copy of `jquery-ui.css` kickes-in and she does not face an unstyled jQuery UI screen.