# insert into tag style css to file .css

Tags: jquery, html, css

can anyone give me example
how to insert tags css into the **.css** file using **jquery**

I have tried several times still can not only able to add css style tags into the head

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You don't need & can't with jQuery - you can manipulate the CSS of elements directly - jQuery will parse and add the `style` attribute for the target element\s.

For a more general approaches who has crossbrowser support in case you are trying to use several different stylesheets read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528965/1486486) about `alternate style-sheets`

You can use plain JS to push some rules or even create new stylesheets using the `document.styleSheets` object. 
For more reading and good examples:

- [Add Rules to Stylesheets with JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets)
- [w3c, Dynamic style - manipulating CSS with JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty unusual task so jQuery doesn't have special handling for it. You can accomplish this with basic javascript however.

Your stylesheets are available with:

```
document.styleSheets
```

You can add to them with insertRule:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("body { width: 100%; }", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sheet = (function () {
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
document.head.appendChild(style);
return style.sheet;
})();
sheet.insertRule("@media all { body { background : red } body { color : black } }", 0);
```