# Why is the code below returning a color value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through jQuery `ready` event and found the following:

> The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

I guess this implies that if I set any CSS property after running the jQuery code, its value won't be reflected in the jQuery code. However, the code extracts the value correctly. Am I missing something? Here is my code:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var theColor = $('p').css('color');
      $('p').text(theColor);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Some Text!</p>
  <style>
    p{ color: rgb(29,65,92); }
  </style>
</body>
```

From my understanding the text should not have changed to `rgb(29,65,92)` in this case but it did. What's the explanation here?

**EDIT:** If the code return correct value because it is wrapped in ready then what does the following statement mean?

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties,
>   it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style
>   elements before referencing the scripts.

Comment: But you *have* wrapped your code in a `.ready` handler! That's not a counter-example to the statement you posted.

Comment: What does "When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts." imply then?

Comment: It means that you either need to reference scripts and style sheets in the right order *or* delay execution of the script until the style is applied (which is what `.ready` does in your example).

Comment: This means that the code inside ready works only after every styling and other such stuff has been applied? I guess I misunderstood the statements because they were written together. Thanks.

Comment: You are not understanding it properly, go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537039/how-to-determine-if-css-has-been-loaded and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready

Comment: As i understand, "the DOM is ready" statement implies that all css styles should be applied, am i right?

Comment: @blindProgrammer [Nope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: @AndréDion Then what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your script and your CSS are internal to the document (i.e., **not** external), so the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) warning does not apply.

What the jQuery documentation is pointing out is that *if* you have external scripts that rely on **computed** CSS values, those values aren't guaranteed to be available at the time `DOMContentLoaded` fires. Instead, you'd want to add a handler for [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Comment: So, this implies that values may or may not be applied. There is not complete surety.

Comment: It means don't rely on `DOMContentLoaded` if you need to query the DOM for CSS values. This is largely dependent on browser implementation. Some browsers (Firefox, Chrome) employ smarter, predictive parsers that would provide computed CSS values at `DOMContentLoaded` time, but the point is not all browsers do that, so it's unreliable.

Comment: Seriously, go and [read the thread that @Anil Kumar already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return `rgb(29,65,92)` when I run it in Safari, opera and IE. These three browsers display `Some Text!` for `<p>` as defined in your HTML. They are ignoring your jQuery code. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. So, I think the order in which you write your `style` and `script` matters in most cases for your page to be consistent across browsers.

> When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties,
>   it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style
>   elements before referencing the scripts.

This probably means, `it might work if you dont do this, but it is important to do this` probably considering cross browser compatibility`