# Detecting load of CSS <link> in modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for more information regarding detection of `<link>` elements being fully loaded and parsed by modern browsers.

I've done a decent amount of research, but everything I dig up is pretty antiquated.

For instance, I found this SO post, [How to determine if CSS has been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537039/how-to-determine-if-css-has-been-loaded). It references a blog posts, [found here](http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/), which references various bug reports for Webkit, Chromium, and Mozilla. However, all those bugs have since been resolved and marked as fixed. (Ref: [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38995), [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185236), and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67522))

Looking at MDN's documentation on link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events, their documentation implies that using `onload` is sufficient, but they don't provide any additional comments on what sort of support it has for older browsers.

My question is simple:

If I am only targeting evergreen browsers -- is using the `onload` event handler sufficient for detecting whether  a CSS file has been loaded? If not, please provide documentation on what patches are required for specific browsers/browser versions.

Comment: check these links - http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/          http://www.zachleat.com/web/load-css-dynamically/

Comment: @ANSHULGERA Please read my post. I reference your first link in my post and explain that I already went through it, but found its information old.

Answer (score -2):

Use a (temporary) garish background colour in your CSS.
If it is loaded it will be instantly obvious.
It can later be commented out exactly the same as in C/C++,
TEST

```
background-color: lime;
```

DEPLOYMENT

```
/*
background-color: lime;
 */
background-color: pale-blue;
```