# Styles are not applied immediately after a <style> tag is inserted

Tags: javascript, css

I have a 3 step process:

1. Insert widget's HTML into the page.
2. Insert widget's style into the page.
3. Read some CSS properties from some elements, and based on values set some other properties.

And everything works fine. Except in some rare cases at step 3 the styles (inserted at step 2) may not be applied yet. This usually happens when a lot of stuff loading and gets initialized on the page in parallel with my code.

I can't extract a simple reproducing example (codebase is very very complex).

My question is: is it guaranteed that after styles are inserted they are immediately applied? If not, are there any APIs that would allow me to run some code after styles applied?

I couldn't find anything about this online. So I would very appreciate if someone could direct me to anything on the subject.

---

The style insertion looks something like this:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. http://jsbin.com/torali/edit?html,js,output What are the "rare cases" you're referring to? We need enough information to reliably reproduce your issue.

Comment: What does the `css` look like you're appending in your code?

Comment: Switch around the logic, insert widget styles first, then insert widgets HTML, so the styles are always available. Style recalculations are done during the repaint or reflow step of browser rendering. This is triggered every time the DOM changes. If you insert the html, it triggers a reflow due to elements being added to the body. But if the styles aren't available yet, they won't be applied until after the next repaint. Depending on the size of the stylesheet, I usually just add all widget styles into the main stylesheet so everythings always available when it comes to styling.

Comment: For reference: This is the same reasoning why styles usually should be as high up in the header as possible and scripts usually as low down in the body. By having styles in the header, you assure all styles are available when the DOM gets created from the HTML code. By inserting script as the last aprt of the body, you assure the full DOM is loaded by the time the scripts arrive and get executed.

Comment: Thanks, @Shilly! I'll try that.

Comment: I got it wrong at first, we actually do insert CSS _before_ HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `<style>` content is not applied until every `<link rel="stylesheet" />` before it in DOM is loaded.

It may work in this way because styles are dependent and rely on order (if there are several rules with the same selector). According to that - browser developers may execute styles in their order in DOM.

Try to wait before adding your style tag:

- till `window.load` event (for testing)
- till all stylesheets are loaded (in production to reduce delay) like here [How to determine if CSS has been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537039/how-to-determine-if-css-has-been-loaded)

P.S. I haven't tested that

Answer (score 0):

Like any other dependencies, CSS files needs to be fetched/parsed/painted. It's difficult to really know exactly when it's going to be downloaded and used.

I think your edge-cases are when it hasn't downloaded fast enough. Would it be possible for you to have the CSS ready to go and use a class on the body to apply the CSS when needed?

Comment: The <style> tags contain styles inside, like `<style>a{color:red}</style>`. They are not loading.

Comment: I understand, what I'm proposing is add that style to an existing CSS file and have it apply with a body class. That way you're not having to dynamically add a <style>

Comment: Not an option for me unfortunately. I'm building a 3rd party widget, that people add to their sites.