# Unable to lookup elements' CSS properties when CSS file loaded manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am loading a `CSS` stylesheet after page load with this code:

```
$("head").append($("<link>", {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    href: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css',
    type: "text/css"
}));
```

Although this works fine (i.e. elements with classes from the newly added stylesheet are properly decorated), I am unable to query the `CSS` properties from that stylesheet using `jQuery`: [I have created a `jsFiddle` to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jUsPh/7/)

**How can I (ideally with `jQuery`) lookup the `CSS` properties of elements which classes correspond to CSS stylesheets added after page load?**

PS: I am experiencing the issue with `Firefox 14.0.1` but not with `Chrome 21.0.1180.79`.

Comment: The stylesheet won't load immediately.

Comment: You also cannot access the stylesheet rules programmatically since it's from different domain... in case you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do your `console.log()` calls in a "load" handler, it works fine:

```
$("head").append($("<link>", {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    href: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css',
    type: "text/css",
    load: function() {
      console.log($('#test1').css('color'));
      console.log($('#test2').css('color'));
      console.log($('#test3').css('color'));
      console.log($('#test4').css('color'));    
      }
  }));
```

[Fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/jUsPh/8/)

Comment: Indeed it works. However I thought `DOM` modifications (i.e. when using methods such as `append`, `prepend` and the likes) where synchronous?

Comment: The DOM is modified immediately, but an HTTP transaction must take place to fetch the stylesheet.  (Even if it's cached, the browser may handle it asynchronously.) It's like adding an `<img>` tag to the document.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the problem is due to the stylesheets not being fully loaded by the time you do your console.logs. Similar to dynamically rendering an image to the page with jquery, a stylesheet is a foriegn resource, and you need to account for the time it takes for the browser to pull down and apply the stylesheet before you can execute code that leverages.

A better approach to this problem (and a solution) can be found here:
[jQuery event that triggers after CSS is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571164/jquery-event-that-triggers-after-css-is-loaded)